# Codeigniter - Need help uploading picture to both folder and database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need help uploading the picture to the folder and database. It seems I can only send it to the database, but not upload it to the folder. Is there anything wrong with the code?

**admin.php (controller)**

```
public function input_siswa(){
    $config['upload_path']          = './gambarfolder/';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']             = '100';
    $config['max_width']            = '1024';
    $config['max_height']           = '768';

    $this->load->library('upload');
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    $location=base_url().'/gambarfolder/';
    $pict=$location.$data_imge;

    $nama_siswa = $this->input->post('nama_siswa');
    $nis = $this->input->post('nis');
    $id_jurusan = $this->input->post('id_jurusan');
    $data = array(
            'nama_siswa'=>$nama_siswa,
            'nis'=>$nis,
            'id_jurusan'=>$id_jurusan,
            'gambar'=>$pict
              );
    $this->m_model->create('siswa',$data);   
    redirect(base_url('index.php/admin/tampil_siswa'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upload image in codeigniter using upload library.

```
public function input_siswa(){
    $config['upload_path']          = './gambarfolder/';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']             = '100';
    $config['max_width']            = '1024';
    $config['max_height']           = '768';

    $location=base_url().'/gambarfolder/';
    $pict=$location.$data_imge;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if ($this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
    {
        $nama_siswa = $this->input->post('nama_siswa');
        $nis = $this->input->post('nis');
        $id_jurusan = $this->input->post('id_jurusan');
        $data = array(

                    'nama_siswa'=>$nama_siswa,
                    'nis'=>$nis,
                    'id_jurusan'=>$id_jurusan,
                    'gambar'=>$pict

                );
        $this->m_model->create('siswa',$data); 
        redirect(base_url('index.php/admin/tampil_siswa'));
        // redirect succsess page when image upload succsessfully.
    }else{
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->load->view('upload', $error);
        // return image upload error.
    }
```

}

Comment: Also you should check your view. The form should be multipart `echo form_open_multipart('controller/input_siswa');` and the file input should be named as _userfile_ otherwise it won't work.

Comment: wait, if the file input is named userfile what about the array for the 'gambar' =>$pict ??

Comment: And it always ended up going to the upload error, i have changed the input name and use the `<?php echo form_open_multipart('admin/input_siswa');?>`

Comment: gamber is your file input field name?

Comment: yes but Eduardo asked me to change that to userfile right?

Comment: not needed just replace userfile to gamber in do_upload()
if ($this->upload->do_upload('gamber'))

Comment: i did it and actually upload it with the multipart but i can't put it to the database, i was thinking about the `$data_image=['file_name']` and `$pict=data_image` but the problem is that i can't call that file name to the $pict

Comment: $data_image=$_FILES['gamber']['name'];

Comment: in $data_image contain your image name

Answer (score 0):

first check your folder gambarfolder is in the root of your codigniter application

second check in your form tag you add  enctype="multipart/form-data"

and add that lines for upload image to gambarfolder  folder

```
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
if($this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
{

}
```

where userfile is the name of file tag like

```
<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />
```

and $config is your config array

and also check https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: i checked it and tried too it seems only send the picture to folder only? not database. Correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: Hi Happy Dog , in your question you have issue about not able to upload picture to folder so my answer is explanation how to upload image to folder so you have to put your code that save into the database inside  if($this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
{

}

Comment: yeah i tried to use both of that but it seems like going to the failed uplad instead of success upload

Comment: be sure you put $config['upload_path']          = './gambarfolder/';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']             = '100';
    $config['max_width']            = '1024';
    $config['max_height']           = '768'; before $this->load->library('upload', $config); and make sure that gambarfolder folder in the root of your application and your form have enctype="multipart/form-data"  like <form action="" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data"> or use form_open_multipart('controller/input_siswa') in your view

Comment: and make sure that your image has types gif|jpg|png and max_size = 100 , max_width=1024 , max_height = 768 as you insert in your $config variable

Comment: okay, it actually uploaded to the folder with that `enctype="multipart/form-data">` but it didn't get in to the database unless if i don't use the enctype it can input to the database

Answer (score 0):

You need to add below line after initialise config

```
$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')
```